# How to plot several coordinates from pymongo plotly and mapbox

Tags: pandas, mongodb, plotly, pymongo, mapbox

I'm working in a project in which i need to plot several coordinates from a mongodb query, i can plot a single result and works awesome, but i need to figure out how to plot several coordinates from the query, the query contains the info needed but i don;t know how to iterate correctly in the result file i think that's my problem , i'm running on circles now so i need some help .

Code that works for a single result :

```
countE2 = mydb.results.find({"d.latitude":{"$gt":0},"d.longitude":{"$gt":0}},{"d.latitude":1, "d.longitude": 1,"a":1,"u.Server":1}).limit(10).sort('t', pymongo.DESCENDING)
for resultado in countE2:
        lat = resultado["d"]["latitude"]
        lon = resultado["d"]["longitude"]
        ip = resultado["a"]
        server = resultado["u"]["Server"]
        us_cities = [lat,lon,ip,server]
        y = us_cities
        print(y)
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(y,lat=[y[0]], lon=[y[1]],hover_name=[y[2]],hover_data=[[y[3]],[y[3]]],color_discrete_sequence=["green"], zoom=3, height=1000)
print(fig)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="dark", mapbox_accesstoken=token)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
```

Please consider that the query returns several results ,in this case countE.

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be possible to make the resulting data from the acquisition into a data frame or a list of each latitude and longitude and set it up with `sacatter_mapbox()`. If you have sample data, I may be able to provide specific assistance.

Comment: yeah yeah , exactly , i think the solution is to create a dataframe and scrap from there the lat and lon, is the only that i need to grab those 2 values, here is the dataset the lt and lon are contained in "d"   :  Index(['_id', 'd'], dtype='object')
0             {'latitude': 35.685, 'longitude': 139.7514}
1                  {'latitude': 60.0, 'longitude': -95.0}
2       {'latitude': 54.94499999999999, 'longitude': -...
3       {'latitude': 41.32740000000001, 'longitude': -...
4       {'latitude': 42.83330000000001, 'longitude': 1...
Name: d, Length: 6005, dtype: object

Comment: Please refer to the official reference for various [examples](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#multiple-markers).